# Dragging 3D objects on walls using mouse in three.js

Tags: three.js, drag

I am trying to achieve movement of an object on walls, instead of only one plane. In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hesamoy/t7rapxu5/), an object dragged on walls by using:

```
intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([walls]);
object.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
```

However, with this method, the object jumps because the object's center moves to the mouse. There is a [related question](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/dragging-3d-objects-using-mouse-in-three-js/12731) and helpful JSFiddle for dragging on one plane without jumpin Would you please help me to modify it for multiples planes (walls)? Thanks

Comment: When you say the object "jumps", do you mean you want the object to be offset a certain distance from the wall so that it's not partially inside of the wall?

Comment: Not actually, I mean when I click on the object, the object's center jumps into the mouse, because of using object.position.copy(intersects[0].point). I know I need to use another function for position such as 'add', so that the position will work incrementally!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, I think what you're looking for is you want the object to animate to the position. You can do this a few ways. The "threejs" way is to move it each frame (within the animate/update loop). You could do this with [Vector3.lerp](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.lerp) by storing `intersects[0].point` as your target location and lerping your `object.position` to it each frame. Another option is to use an animation library like animejs or gsap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for handling movements not animation.

Comment: The movement of an object is the animation of an object.

Comment: I am not looking for animation or movement to a position during a specific time, however, it is okay to jump over a new place however, the movement should be correct!